# Dynamically selecting Dropdown's options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am having a dropdown. When the page loads I want to select the option based on the value.

I have a hash which contains id as key and some number as its value. I am looping through this hash and if any of the option's value matches the current loop's value I need to set that option as selected.

```
$.each(hash_name_here, function(key, value){
  $('select option[value=key]').attr("selected',"selected");
});
```

This does nothing.

But if I substitute the number instead of key it works fine.

```
$('select option[value=81]').attr("selected',"selected");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have used key as a string literal in your selector. It would treat is as 'find the option which is having `value="key"`...not the `value=valueOf(key)` as passed in the function.

Comment: value=key consider as a string , so just give like value='+key+'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to let Jquery know that key is a variable. Now it's parsed as a string.
Use:

```
$.each(hash_name_here, function(key, value){
  $('select option[value=' + key + ']').attr("selected","selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(hash_name_here, function(key, value){  
  $('#key option[value=value]').prop("selected",true);
});
```